# How to change the less variables and recompile it using webpack-angular project?

Tags: webpack, less, precompile, theming

Can anyone help me with this if anyone has tried to theme their site with global variables using less and Webpack and could recompile the less to css.

NOTE: i'm using a Webpack loader and extractTextPlugin that generates a single styles.css for all the less file sin the project.

### 1.    Getting and setting the theme from the rest api

```
let getThemes = function(){
                   let options = {
                url:__env.apiUrl+'/UserProfile/GetAccountTheme',
                type:"GET",
                postInfo:null,
                session:true,
              }
              ajaxService.ajaxData(options).then(a => {
                if(a.statusText == "OK" && a.status == 200 && a.data){
                  console.log(a);
                  var brandcolor = a.data[0].Value;
                  var secondarycolor = a.data[1].Value;
                  less.modifyVars({ "brand-color":brandcolor, "secondary-color": secondarycolor });
                  less.refresh();                 
                }
                },(err) => {  
                  console.log(err);
              });
  }();
```

### 2. default var.less file

```
@white:#fff;
@brand-color:  #ff9231;
@title-color:#747778;
@dark-color: #4F4F4F;
@blue-bgcolor: @secondary-color; //#5DAEE0;
@white-color:#ffffff;
@light-bgcolor:#fafafa;
@border-error:1px solid #f44336 !important;
@error: #f44336;
@box-color:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.24), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12);;
@border-color:1px solid #E5E5E5;
@primary-color: #ff9231; //#41dec2;
@secondary-color: #5DAEE0; //#e039c5;
```

### 3. Webpack.config file actually renders a single stle.css file for all the less files in the modules i have (I have added the portion of the webconfig file)

```
 module:{
    loaders:[
      {test: /\.js$/,loader:'babel-loader',query: {presets: ["es2015"],compact: false},exclude: '/node_modules/'},  
      {test: /\.less$/,loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','less'])},   
      {test: /\.css$/,loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css'])},  
      {test: /\.html$/,loader: "html?config=otherHtmlLoaderConfig"},
      {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader:'url-loader',query:{limit:100000}},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
      {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }  
    ]
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css',{ allChunks: true }), 
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendor.min.js'),
    new VendorChunkPlugin('vendor'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template:path.join(__dirname,'app','index.html')}),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
```

Comment: please show your code that you've tried

Comment: thanks @PraveshKhatri i have updated my question